# SharePoint 2013 C# get all websites and sort alphabetically

Tags: 2013, development, visual-web-part, sorting, c-sharp

I am currently building a visual webpart for an on premise SharePoint farm in C#.

I am currently able to get all of the webs and also get all of the list items within each web, using the CAML Query I am also able to sort the list items alphabetically but I am however unable to sort the webs.

The application currently returns the `web.title` but in any order, it is a requirement to have this sorted alphabetically. This is how the code currently looks:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl)) {
    foreach(SPWeb web in site.AllWebs) {
        try {
            using(SPWeb webList = site.OpenWeb(web.Url.Substring(siteUrl.Length))) {
                //check if our list exists wherever we are currently
                SPList list = webList.Lists.TryGetList("Faqs");
                if (list != null) {
                    rv += "<h3><a onclick=\"toggle_visibility('" + web.ID + "');\">" + web.Title + "</a><span onclick=\"toggle_visibility('" + web.ID + "');\"></span></h3>";
                    rv += "<div>";
                    rv += "<ul id=\"" + web.ID + "\" style=\"display:none;\">";
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy>";
                    foreach(SPListItem item in list.GetItems(query)) {
                        rv += "<li>";
                        rv += "<a href=\"" + web.Url + "/Pages/page.aspx>\n\r";
                        rv += item["something"].ToString() + "<br />";
                        rv += "</a>\r\n";
                        rv += "</li>\r\n";
                    }
                    rv += "</ul>";
                    rv += "</div>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I basically want to sort by the `web.title` I have tried JavaScript but so far not had any luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `site.AllWebs` returns an object of [`SPWebCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebcollection(v=office.14).aspx) which inherits from [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.100).aspx) interface. This interface has a function called [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) using which you can order the `SPWeb` based on their `Title` property.

```
SPWebCollection webColl = site.AllWebs;
IEnumerable<SPWeb> sortWebColl = webColl.OrderBy(w => w.Title);
foreach (SPWeb web in sortWebColl) {
    // Code
}
```

Make sure you use the following namespaces otherwise it will throw error.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```